# Homotopies in the Moebius strip

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Lel $I:=[0,1]$ and consider the Moebius strip $M:=I\times I/\sim$ defined quotienting $I\times I$. If I consider the boundary of $M$, we call it $B$, then $B$ is parametrized by the map $\pi\circ \beta$, where $\pi$ is the quotient map and the other map is defined as follows

\begin{align*}
\beta\colon I & \longrightarrow I\times I\\
t &\longmapsto \bigg\{  \begin{array}{ll}
  (1,2t)  & \mbox{if } 0\leq t<1/2 \\
  (0,2t-1) & \mbox{if } 1/2\leq t\leq 1
 \end{array}.
\end{align*}
Taking $(0,0)$ as base-point, I want prove that there exist a base-point preserving homotopy between the loop $\pi\circ \beta$ and the loop defined by \begin{align*}
\mu\colon I & \longrightarrow I\times I/\sim\\
t &\longmapsto \bigg\{  \begin{array}{ll}
  \pi(2t,2t)  & \mbox{if } 0\leq t<1/2 \\
  \pi(2t-1,2t-1) & \mbox{if } 1/2\leq t\leq 1
 \end{array}.
\end{align*}
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You've almost written it yourself! If you let $s$ range from $0$ to $t$ and define

\begin{align*}
H(s, t) &\longmapsto \bigg\{  \begin{array}{ll}
  (2s,2t)  & \mbox{if } 0\leq t<1/2 \\
  (2s-1,2t-1) & \mbox{if } 1/2\leq t\leq 1
 \end{array}.
\end{align*}

then $\pi \circ H$ defines a homotopy (if I've got your identifications right). but since we usually like for $s$ to go from $0$ to $1$, we can define

\begin{align*}
K(s, t) &\longmapsto \bigg\{  \begin{array}{ll}
  (2st,2t)  & \mbox{if } 0\leq t<1/2 \\
  (2st-1,2t-1) & \mbox{if } 1/2\leq t\leq 1
 \end{array}.
\end{align*}

and this gives (I think!) the desired homotopy.